# How do I use my mobile input results in another scripts if statement? C# Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm using this script 
http://www.thegamecontriver.com/2014/08/unity3d-swipe-input-for-touch-screen.html

which basically detects swipes on my android device.

How do I use this script in my character controller's if statement?

For example:

```
if(**swipescript detects swipe right** && character is idle)
{
    move character right
}
```

The part in asterisk is what I need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the script you posted link to is named `SwipeControl`, you can add a public `boolean` variable called `swipedRight`. Each time player swipes right, set it to true.

Then in your main script where you are suppose to check for that condition, set it to `false` when it is `true`.

In `SwipeControl`:

```
    public bool swipedRight = false;
//Check if drag distance is greater than 20% of the screen height
        if (Mathf.Abs(lp.x - fp.x) > dragDistance || Mathf.Abs(lp.y - fp.y) > dragDistance)
        {//It's a drag
              //check if the drag is vertical or horizontal 
              if (Mathf.Abs(lp.x - fp.x) > Mathf.Abs(lp.y - fp.y))
              {   //If the horizontal movement is greater than the vertical movement...
                  if ((lp.x>fp.x))  //If the movement was to the right)
                  {   //Right swipe
                      //Set Swiped Right to true
                      swipedRight  = true;
                      Debug.Log("Right Swipe");
                  }
                  else
                  {   //Left swipe
                      Debug.Log("Left Swipe"); 
                  }
              }
            else
            {   //the vertical movement is greater than the horizontal movement
                 if (lp.y>fp.y)  //If the movement was up
                 {   //Up swipe
                     Debug.Log("Up Swipe"); 
                 }
                 else
                 {   //Down swipe
                     Debug.Log("Down Swipe");
                 }
            }
        }
```

Then from the other Script:

```
public CharacterController cController;
Rigidbody ccRigidBody;

SwipeControl swipeControl;

void Start()
{
        //Get reference to SwipeControl script
        swipeControl = GameObject.Find("GameObjectSwipeControlIsAttachedTo").GetComponent<SwipeControl>();

        //Get reference to the Rigidbody in the CharacterController
        ccRigidBody = ccRigidBody.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update()
{
        if (swipeControl.swipedRight && ccRigidBody.velocity==Vector3.zero)
        {
            //Do your stuff here


            //Then set swipedRight to false
            swipeControl.swipedRight = false;
        }else if(swipeControl.swipedRight){
            swipeControl.swipedRight = false;
        }
}
```

So your `if(**swipescript detects swipe right** && character is idle)` code is translated to `if (swipeControl.swipedRight && ccRigidBody.velocity==Vector3.zero)` in the code above.

Comment: Sweet. The first part of the script works (from that website) and I understand what you mean by making swipeControl set to false after it goes through the if statement.                                                                                  Though my character doesn't have a rigidbody component, or anything really. The only thing attached to it is a script. The character idle is just an animator component.

Comment: @itsPav If the character idle is just an animator component, then replace `ccRigidBody.velocity==Vector3.zero` with the animator idle code. This should work. If this solved your problem you can go ahead and close it by accepting it as answer.

Comment: I've removed everything related to rigidbody in the code above and replaced it with my animator idle statement. Still get the object reference not set to an instance of an object at line 60. which would be...if (swipeControl.swipedRight && idle == true)

Comment: Nope, I get that console error constantly popping up and swiping doesn't seem to do anything. The console does say right swipe as it should from script one. Script 2 (player control) gets the console error.

Comment: @itsPav Dude you post the console error. How am I am suppose to know your error? Do you really need help? And by the way you are suppose to change your `GameObjectSwipeControlIsAttachedTo` to the name of GameObject `swipeControl`  is attached to.